# Is there a word for the belief in truth?

Tags: epistemology, truth

I just wonder if there is a word for the belief in truth to look it up and learn more about it.

Comment: Do you mean a belief that at least one sentence is truth-apt?

Comment: I mean the belief in the existence of truth. I should have made that more clear, sorry.

Comment: The tempting answer is realism, but that word is often prefaced with others that give it another meaning. I can't find a suitable prefix that makes clear we mean what you want.

Comment: *Anti-skepticism* can be the general all-inclusive term for the belief of some objectively existent truth. However, truth can be defined in a variety of different philosophical flavors, such as conditional correspondence to the existence of some state affairs, morally driven ideals or pursuits, and in some situations it cannot even be defined at all in which case one may lead to Camus-like absurdism or stipulate subjective truth according to ones' own hopefully consistent philosophy...

Comment: @DoubleKnot that's more of an answer than a comment.

Comment: Depends on what truth (absolute truth does not exist). Who believes in religious truth is perhaps a _religious_, etc.

Comment: @J.G. In the book *Metametaphysics* David Chalmers talks about a position called "ontological anti-realism" which, if I'm understanding correctly, accepts that there are truths about the world but denies any objective fact about which terms in the true propositions refer to "existing things" and which do not (for example, we can say there are two cups on the table without worrying about whether 'two cups' is a distinct existing thing separate from either individual cup, likewise we could say an apple is red without worrying about whether the color red exists as an entity in and of itself)

Comment: @DoubleKnot are anti-scepticists also dogmatists?

Comment: Not necessarily, a large portion of modern epistemologists are non-dogmatists such as Kant.

Comment: Since you now said „epistemologists“, are they always skepticists?

Comment: Skepticists have always been a challenge and propelling force in philosophy since the beginning from schools like [Pyrrhonism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhonism), [Academic Skepticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_skepticism) in western philosophy. But epistemologists are not necessarily skepticists (otherwise why need different labels?) but of course always ready to resolve or mitigate challenges from problems posed by skepticists such as the modern famous epistemic [Gettier problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettier_problem)...

Comment: And in eastern philosophies truth are more often stipulated as some moral ideals and are termed wildly distinctly across different cultures. For example in Sufism belief in truth can be called *[La Ilaha Ila Allah Hu](https://religion.fandom.com/wiki/Hu_(Sufism))*, and in Mahayana Buddhism it can be called *Lotus Flower Belief* mentioned in many sutras such as [Shurangama](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama17.asp.html)...

Answer (score -2):

I will go for Intuition if we talk about a specific truth but at an ontological level it depends on whether you believe there is truth or not. If you do then your belief is faith and if you don't then you are a nihilist.
To sum it up it all depends on truth and what it means to us or you.